# Doctrine2: How to select ArrayCollection using DQL

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've two entities which has `OneToMany` mapping just the way described in doctrine docs:

```
 // Product Entity
 /**
  * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Feature", mappedBy="product")
  */
  private $features;

 // Feature Entity    
 /**
  * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="features")
  * @JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
  */
  private $product;
```

When I do `findAll()` on `Product` then it returns products with array of `Feature`.

I'm using `DQL` to query and so I want to know how do I select array of `Feature` using `DQL`.

I did: `SELECT p.name, p.price, f FROM Product p JOIN p.features f`

but it gives an error

> Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.

I also tried: `SELECT p.name, p.price, p.features FROM Product p`

which also gives an error

> Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: Can you please ost your PHP code also? The DQL does not look wrong by itself, but maybe how you are calling it is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't get the Features entities without getting a Product for contain it. So you must do

```
SELECT p , f FROM Product p JOIN p.features f
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

@abdiel gives right solution

```
class ProductsRepository extends \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
{

    public function getAllProductsWithFeatures()
    {
        $dql = 'SELECT p , f FROM Product p JOIN p.features f';
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery($dql);
        return $query->getResult();
    }

}
```

Then for example in controller:

```
$products = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('YourBundle:Product')->getAllProductsWithFeatures();
```

All products will be with preloaded collections of features.

Good luck!